# require_once() [function.require]: Failed opening required

Tags: php, codeigniter, require-once

I have searching for a solution for this one but nothing seems to work for me, the deal is that I have already use `require_once` in other project with the same library (PHPExcel) and worked very well, but now I don't know what's wrong.

I'm using CodeIgniter in both projects but I can't figure out if it's PHP version problem or if Im doing something wrong.
So, here's the code:

```
$this->load->library('PHPExcel');
require_once (base_url().'applications/proyect/libraries/PHPExcel/Cell/AdvancedValueBinder.php');
```

and this is displayed:

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: Users::require_once(http://localhost/my_proyect/applications/proyect/libraries/PHPExcel/Cell/AdvancedValueBinder.php) [function.Usuarios-require-once]: failed to open stream: 
An error occurred during the connection attempt because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or there was an error in the connection established because connected host has failed to respond

Fatal error: Users::require_once() [function.require]: 
Failed opening required 'http://localhost/my_proyect/applications/proyect/libraries/PHPExcel/Cell/AdvancedValueBinder.php' (include_path='.;C:\php5\pear'
```

I'm not sure what's the `C:\php5\pear` thing, but I can't handle with this `require_once` problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use codeigniter in correct way.

**SUGGESTION:** Since it is a library you don't have to include it precisely. Move the library file to `applications/libraries` directory and -

1) You can autoload it in `config/autoload.php`

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('my_library');
```

2) Or you can specifically load into your required controller

```
<?php
class Something extends MY_Controller
{
    public function __construct()
   {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->library('my_library');
   }

   public function my_function()
   {
        ...
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I am using the phpExcel inside the libraries folder and call the load->library and phpExcel works fine now, I did it that way because i had experience some trouble with an earlier proyect and it was neccesary to use require_once. The problem is there with the require but I don't have to use it anymore, so this is partialy solved

Comment: Glad it helped! Partially ;)

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to `require` a file over an HTTP connection, and the connection failed.  You should `require` the file using the disk path wherever possible.

Comment: mmm I don't think using the disk path would work for me, thats why I'm using base_url(), but thanks!

Comment: ahh, that's because i'm working with job teammates that doesn't have exp with codeigniter and the app will be installed by them, I'm temporally in here and I won't be here when they'll have to do the installation and future migrations, and i'm thinking that you're saying that what i need to do is put the absolute path?

Comment: Yeah, probably the best thing to do is make yourself a `config.php` with `$codeIgniterPath = '/foo';` and then use `require_once $codeIgniterPath . '/whatever.php';` then when it gets deployed, all the other guys have to do is change the path in `config.php`.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use

```
base_url();
```

You can use

```
APPPATH
```

it's constant

```
   require_once(APPPATH.'applications/proyect/libraries/PHPExcel/Cell/AdvancedValueBinder.php');
```